How can I configure the NextJS dev server?
If I'm understanding it correctly, NextJS is using the webpack dev server (unless you're opting into Turbopack) - and webpack can be configured via the webpack property of the next.config.js file (Documentation here).
I'm trying to add some headers to my responses like, per webpack configuration options:
const nextConfig: NextConfig = {
  webpack: (config)  => {
      if (!config.devServer){
        config.devServer = {};
      }
  
      config.devServer.headers = () => {
  
        return [{
          key: "hello", 
          value: "world"
        }]
      }
  }
}


However, this appears to not have any effect.
Is there a canonical reference to configuring the dev server for NextJS somewhere?

For posterity - I created a github issue here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/71947
